# Add-Migration creating empty migration in code migrations/code first

Tags: ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using code migrations in code first.  I modified one of my models (domain class) and changes were picked up when I added a migration.  So far so good.  Now is the part where I may be doing something wrong:

1. I made additional changes making the previous modification irrelevant.
2. I deleted the migration and tried to re-scaffold, I got an empty migration.  I understand now that the database tracks migration history. So I understand why this was stupid.
3. My next step was to delete the rows in the database- it also sounds like this is not a good idea.  The appropriate way to "step-back" is to do Update-Database -Target:{MigrationName}
4. Trying both of these I am still getting an empty migration.  I also tried dropping the database and updating to the migration before mine.

My google/SO foo has failed me.  What I think is happening is that VS/Entity is not detecting changes in my model and I'm not sure what the trigger is.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. If you found a solution please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  My solution was to just go forward with a substance-less migration happening.  The only change it makes is adding a record to the __Migration table,  but I am living with that and just moving forward.